# npm ERR! fn.apply is not a function

Tags: cordova, npm

I am working on cordova based project. I am using codova for a long time and everything was fine. The problem started when I tried to add "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation". It gave me the error:

**I:\Projects\ecom>cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation**

> Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-geolocation@4.0.2 via
>   registry.
>  Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin
>   spec is incorrect.
>  Check your connection and plugin
>   name/version/URL.
>  Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1
>   Error output:
>  npm ERR! fn.apply is not a function npm ERR! A
>   complete log of this run can be found in:
>  npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-08T11_45_18_290Z-debug.log

cordova create , cordova run android, these commands are working fine. I checked version of cordova:

I:\Projects\ecom>cordova -v
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

I uninstalled and reinstall npm. 
but, it didn't resolve the issue.

Moreover when I tried to update npm globaly, it gives me the same error.

**I:\Projects\ecom>npm update -g**

> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2:
>   request has been deprecated, see
>   https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
>  npm WARN deprecated
>   core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended
>   for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your
>   dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>  npm ERR! fn.apply
>   is not a function
>  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found
>   in:
>  npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-08T12_30_22_636Z-debug.log

I am including the last few lines of debug file :

> 23 verbose stack TypeError: fn.apply is not a function
>  23 verbose
>   stack     at Array.
>   (C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\bind-actor.js:15:8)
>   23 verbose stack     at LOOP
>   (C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:15:14)
>   23 verbose stack     at
>   C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:18:7
>   23 verbose stack     at
>   C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\check-permissions.js:32:32
>   23 verbose stack     at cb
>   (C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:47:24)
>   23 verbose stack     at
>   C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\check-permissions.js:67:5
>   23 verbose stack     at RES
>   (C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\inflight\inflight.js:31:16)
>   23 verbose stack     at f
>   (C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
>   23 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:154:23)

The problem is I can't add a new platform or plugin to my cordova project.

**This is npm error.**

*Thanks in Advance*